# jQuery infinite scroll, pagination link from data

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I have a custom jQuery infinite scroll script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var footer = jQuery('.pagination'),
    opts = {
        offset: '100%'
    };
    footer.waypoint(function(event, direction) {
        footer.waypoint('remove');
        jQuery.get(jQuery('.pagination-next a').attr('href'), function(data) {
            var data = jQuery(data);
            jQuery('#timeline').append(data.find('.timeline-item'));
            footer.waypoint(opts);
        });
    }, opts);
});
```

I am using waypoints plugin to detect view port.
My problem is : I want to `attr` href from the data page, currtly my code `attr` href form the same page and its load same content everytime cause `.pagination-next a` link was same on the current page. if i am able to get  next `.pagination-next a` link from data page then it will solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have a `.pagination-next a` in the next data page loaded? If it is the case then I think remove the previous next-link will solve your problem; as my guess is that you still have multiple next-links in your page and the `jQuery.get` call will use the first link present in the `jQuery('.pagination-next a')` collection (which is the old one).

I think it's just as easy as:

```
footer.waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    footer.waypoint('remove');
    jQuery.get(jQuery('.pagination-next a').remove().attr('href'), function(data) {
        jQuery('#timeline').append(jQuery(data).find('.timeline-item'));
        footer.waypoint(opts);
    });
}, opts);
```